# react router passing variable/state to new route?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, router

I have a dynamic variable that is made in one component and then that component routes to another component. How do i pass the variable?

COMPONENT A

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Event extends React.Component {
   makeVariable(event)
   { myVariable = '123abc' }

   {window.location.replace("/B")}

   render () { return (html for page A)
}
export default A;
```

COMPONENT B

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class B extends Component {
    render(){ console.log(myVariable)}
}
export default B;
```

ROUTES FILE

```
export const makeMainRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
        <div>
          <Route path="/A" render={(props) => <App auth={auth} {...props} />} />
          <Route path="/B" render={(props) => <Home auth={auth} {...props} />} />
)}
```

Comment: How/ when do you want the data to be passed?
By clicking on a button perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React Router 4 you should be able to access query params via `props.location.search`.

Component A

```
window.location.replace(`/B?myVariable=${myVariable}`);
```

Component B

```
import queryString from 'query-string';

render() {
  console.log(queryString.parse(this.props.location.search).myVariable));
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works, but what if i wanted myVariable to hold an object? doesn't seem to work it gives me {createdEvent: "[object Object]"}

Comment: It seems like what you really want is a global state manager like Redux if you'll be passing objects between route-level components. The query param approach is only useful for simple cases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you're asking, but I'll assume it is :)

Let's say this is the data you want to send from component A to component B.

```
const yourData = [{name: 'Tom', age: 28}, {name: 'Sara', age: 25}, {name: 'Rick', age: 34}];
```

You can use the `Link` tag to pass the data from one component to another, like this:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/component/b`, state: { yourData } }}></Link>
```

[maybe add a button tag so a user can click on it, go to the next route, where the necessary data is going to be passed] ... and then, in component B you can access your data like this:

`const passedData= this.props.history.location.state.yourData;`

Comment: thank you for your help here i think this is for routing to a new link through a button click or link click, but i need to go to a new route from inside a function so the first response seems more like what i need i think